# Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GcmBroadcastReceiver:

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have imported the project from https://code.google.com/p/gcm/

it's build and when i run the project, sometime my app is crashing and giving me an error like

```
     12-03 19:26:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(17274): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GcmBroadcastReceiver
     12-03 19:26:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2222)
     12-03 19:26:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:138)
     12-03 19:26:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
     12-03 19:26:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     12-03 19:26:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
     12-03 19:26:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
     12-03 19:26:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     12-03 19:26:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

     12-03 19:26:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
     12-03 19:26:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
     12-03 19:26:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     12-03 19:26:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(17274): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GcmBroadcastReceiver
     12-03 19:26:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
     12-03 19:26:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
     12-03 19:26:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
     12-03 19:26:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2217)
     12-03 19:26:20.416: E/AndroidRuntime(17274):   ... 10 more
     12-03 19:26:22.496: I/Process(17274): Sending signal. PID: 17274 SIG: 9
```

but GcmBroadcastReceiver is in my package

[image]

and also in manifest declaration is also properly

[image]

source code on Click event is

```
      public void onClick(final View view) {

    if (view == findViewById(R.id.send)) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    Bundle data = new Bundle();
                    data.putString("my_message", "Hello World");
                    data.putString("my_action", "com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ECHO_NOW");
                    String id = Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet());
                    System.out.println("GCM Adhyakhs = "+SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com");
                    gcm.send(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com", id, data);
                    msg = "Sent message";
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
```

Comment: Clean and restart eclipse...

Comment: i have do it also uninstall and install app but same error :(

Comment: have you check if there is no minor change with package name?

Comment: ya that's why!!! i have checked that but no any change it's same :(

Comment: i am mostly getting error when i press send button :(

Comment: add code for that.............

Comment: it's copy of https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/DemoActivity.java class

Comment: have you seen this??http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: ya but it is using deprecated method now gcm uses new method